# Creating a for-in loop that prints out players name and score in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, for-in-loop

```
var players = ["Donna", "Craig", "Brian", "Anna"]

let scores = [2, 2, 4, 5]


for (indexx, score) in scores.enumerate() {

for (index, player) in players.enumerate() {
        if indexx != index {
            continue
        }
        print("Player's Name: \(player) Score: \(score)")

    }
}
```

I made this method using what I have learned so far about for-in loops and arrays. Is there a more sufficient way of creating a for-in loop that prints out a players name and score?

```
Player's Name: Donna Score: 2
Player's Name: Craig Score: 2
Player's Name: Brian Score: 4
Player's Name: Anna Score: 5
```

Answer (score 2):

Given your 2 arrays

```
var players = ["Donna", "Craig", "Brian", "Anna"]
let scores = [2, 2, 4, 5]
```

you can write

```
zip(players, scores).forEach {
    print("Player's Name: \($0.0) Score: \($0.1)")
}
```

and this is the output

```
Player's Name: Donna Score: 2
Player's Name: Craig Score: 2
Player's Name: Brian Score: 4
Player's Name: Anna Score: 5
```